# Redirect to another page when I click on a country using jvector map

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I'm using a jQuery plugin called jVectorMap. Specifically I'm using this map: http://jvectormap.com/maps/world/world/

Every country has a unique`data-code` e.g. `ES` for Spain but I'm unable to access it. For example I've done the following jQuery code:

```
$('path').on('click', function(){
    var country = $(this).data('code');
    console.log(country);
});
```

does nothing. here's the HTML so it should be working.

```
<path d="asiunaowifh" data-code="ES"
fill="#333" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" 
stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" class="jvectormap-region jvectormap-element" 
cursor="pointer">
</path>
```

any idea why not? if someone could look at the [documentation](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/) or give some advice thad be great.

Comment: A minor working example (on jsfiddle, for example) would be fine. I guess that you are binding the click before the `path` element is created. Check that you are binding to it AFTER it exists on the DOM for it to work, but cannot fully tell until an example is shown.

Comment: My jvector map is initially set to `display: none`, could that have an effect?

Comment: No problem with that as long as is on the DOM

Comment: `onRegionClick` did the trick. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the [documentation](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/jvm-map/), there is a special option for the `vectorMap()` called `onRegionClick` which works:

```
$('#map').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill', 
    onRegionClick: function(event, code) {
        console.log(code);
    }
});
```